# Ionic 2 / 3 : Show and hide ion-tab / tab dynamically

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, tabs, ionic3

I’m currently trying to show and hide tabs on a page of mine dynamically.

My question is, how do you do that?

I tried declaring a variable in home.ts called `seeTabs: boolean = false;`
But somehow I can’t assign it’s value to the tab.
I tried doing

```
<ion-tab … show=seeTabs …></ion-tab>
```

I also tried

```
show=“seeTabs”, show=this.seeTabs, show=“this.seeTabs”
```

but nothing works.
Do you have any idea how to do this?
I mean I tried doing what the documentation said…
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tab/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The right syntax is `<ion-tab [show]="seeTabs"></ion-tab>`

Hope it helps.

`export class UserListPage { seeTabs ;}`

`ionViewDidLoad() { this.seeTabs = false;}`

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer!